# SwiftR invoke error: send fails when joining a SignalR group

Tags: swift, signalr, swiftr

I am currently working on a chat app, for which I use SignalR with the framework SwiftR for the ios-client. I already got my chat to work, but connecting to the hub took to long, so I started refactoring and I wrote a SignalRHandler. I used the exact same code but I always got an Error during the negotiaion process, so I changed `connection.useWKWebView = true` to `false`, since `false` is default. It worked after that but now I can't get it to join a group. I had a joinCommunity function which was working, but now I always get the following error message:

```
SwiftR invoke error: {
    message = "Error: Send failed.";
    source = Exception;
}
```

Could it be because I changed the `useWKWebView`?

Here's my whole code from the SignalRHandler

```
import Foundation
import SwiftR

class SignalRHandler{

    var chatHub: Hub!
    var connection: SignalR!
    static let instance = SignalRHandler()

    var url: String

    init() {
        url = "url"
    }


    func setupSignalRConnection(){
        connection = SignalR(url)
        connection.useWKWebView = false
        connection.signalRVersion = .v2_2_0
        chatHub = Hub("communities")
        connection.addHub(chatHub)

        connection.starting = { [weak self] in
            print("connection starting")
        }

        connection.reconnecting = { [weak self] in
            print("connection reconnecting")
        }

        connection.connected = { [weak self] in
            print("Connection ID: \(self!.connection.connectionID!)")
            print("connected")
        }

        connection.reconnected = { [weak self] in
            print("reconnenected")
        }

        connection.disconnected = { [weak self] in
            print("disconnected")
        }

        connection.connectionSlow = { print("Connection slow...") }

        connection.error = { [weak self] error in
            print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")

            if let source = error?["source"] as? String, source == "TimeoutException" {
                print("Connection timed out. Restarting...")
                self?.connection.start()
            }
        }

        connection.start()

    }

    func joinCommunity(userName: String, selectedCommunity: String){
        if let communityHub = chatHub{
            do {
                try chatHub.invoke("JoinCommunity", arguments: [selectedCommunity,userName])
                //                getOldMessages()
                print("Join worked with\(userName, selectedCommunity)")
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

        }
    }


    func leaveCommunity(userName: String, selectedCommunity: String){
        if let communityHub = chatHub{
            do{
                try communityHub.invoke("leaveCommunity", arguments: [selectedCommunity,userName])
                print("the user left the community")
            }catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```